# Testing mailer (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm trying to test my mailer for failure cases, one for example would be if the user did not input a name.

this is my test code

```
test "should not send email without name field" do
  mail = ContactMailer.contact_email("", "jh01023@surrey.ac.uk" , "07982900823",  "Thank you for your email!")

  assert_select mail.name do
  assert_select "[value=?]", address.mail.name unless address.mail.name.blank?
end
```

This is my mailer.

```
def contact_email(name, email, telephone,  message)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @telephone = telephone
    @message = message

    mail cc: @email
end
```

this is my validation page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
</div>
<div>
 <body>
  <h1><u><%= t('contactpage.contactus') %></u></h1>
  <p><%= t('contactpage.complete') %></p>
  <%= form_tag request_contact_path, :id => 'contact_form', method: 'post' do %>
  <br>
  <%= label_tag :name, t('mailer.name') %>
  <%= text_field_tag :name, '', title: "Enter Name", size: 20, :autofocus => true, :required => true%>
  <br>  
  <%= label_tag :email, t('mailer.email') %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, '', title: "Enter Email", :autofocus => true, :required => true%>
  <br> 
  <%= label_tag :telephone, t('mailer.telephone') %>
  <%= telephone_field_tag :telephone, '', title: "Enter Telephone", :autofocus => true, :required => true%>
  <br> 
  <%= label_tag :message, t('mailer.message') %>
  <%= text_field_tag :message, '', title: "Enter Message", size: 100, :autofocus => true, :required => true%>
  <br>  
  <%= submit_tag t('mailer.submit'), name: nil %>
<% end %>
</body>
</div>

<div>
<script>
$("contact_form").validate();  
</script>
</div>
</html>
```

I appreciate any thoughts on how i could edit the assertion test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rails' default configuration sending an email in the test environment wont actually send an email, but it will be appended to `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`

so in your test run the code that delivers the email (and shouldn't if there's no name) and check whether the size of `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` has changed.

```
test "should not send email without name field" do
  assert_no_difference 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size' do
    # run code that operates mailer, but without name
    post request_contact_url, params: {
        name: '',
        email: 'friend@example.com',
        telephone: '12345678',
        message: 'test message'
    }
  end
end
```

I put an empty string for name because I think that is what might come through if the user leaves it empty in the form. You might also want to try testing it with a string with only whitespece characters and also with the name parameter left out.

see the [mailers section of the Rails Guide on testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-your-mailers)